# How to trace Golang's slow compile?

Tags: go, compilation

I have a company's project, which took about 13s to compile on SSD on even minor changes. My other projects only took 1.55-1.79s to recompile on minor changes (0.42s when nothing changed). How to trace which package/part that causes this lag?

there's no `import "C"` in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [undocumented flag](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37591) to show timings of each steps:

```
go build -debug-actiongraph=compile.json
```

Comment: I've written a little program to visualise the content of actiongraph: https://github.com/unravelin/actiongraph

Answer (score 2):

you could add `-x` option to your `go build` command to use debugging mode